# Java Generics and A implements B

Tags: java, generics

I know in Java Generics, there is T extends something, but I want T implements something.

Is there any way to achieve this other than using the explicit cast?

For instance, I want to make sure everything passed to sorting algorithm implements Comparable. Implements, not extends.

Thank you.

Comment: `<T implements something>` would be `<something>`

Comment: If `T` must be something specific, then it is not generic. Thus `T` should be replaced which `something specific`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns then I have to use explict cast

Comment: I think you should take a look to [Java documentation about Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: @Jonas ? extends T and ? super T can achieve PECS，how to achieve that with implements?

Comment: @Jonas For instance, I want to make sure everything passed to sorting algorithm has implemented Comparable

Comment: @Ragtian For a sorting algorithm I would not make the class it self parametrized with a type, but instead have the sort function to take a collection of `Comparable` objects. Try have a look here (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/20sorting/).

Comment: @Jonas Thank you dude. Seems I have to read Thinking in Java again.

Comment: I always found it peculiar: with generics the syntax to use for `T implements MyInterface` is `T extends MyInterface`. So just use `T extends Comparable<T>` even though `Comparable is an interface and you really mean “implements”.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried your approach. Thank you for educating me. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generic type bounds, `extends` isn't limited to classes; you can also use it for interfaces.  For example, `<T extends Runnable>` is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your time. ? extends T and ? super T can achieve PECS，how to achieve that with implements?

Comment: I think an example with an interface would be better ;)

Comment: For instance, I want to make sure everything passed to sorting algorithm has implemented Comparable

Comment: @StefanWarminski, oops, for some reason I was thinking `Number` was an interface.  Thanks for pointing that out.  :-)

Comment: @Rangtian <T extends Comparable<T>>

Comment: @StefanWarminski Thank you for educating me :D